# How do I use a code-cell print function only to render a hyperlink plus text in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The following link allows for a way to render an HTML URL inside a python3 `print()` function within a Jupyter notebook code cell,

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/7393#issue-510053776,

which defines a custom URL class,

```py
"""URL Wrapper."""

from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Url:
    """Wrapper around a URL string to provide nice display in IPython environments."""

    __url: str

    def _repr_html_(self):
        """HTML link to this URL."""
        return f'<a href="{self.__url}">{self.__url}</a>' # problem here (*)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return the underlying string."""
        return self.__url
```

The commentator notes that one must use `str(url())` to achieve the desired result.

Unlike (I think) the now built-in rendering of this, I am trying to use this custom class thus:

```py
linker = lambda my_string: str(Url('https://www.google.com/%s' % my_string))
print('URL for my_string is here',linker('search'))
```

I would like the `linker('search')` to render as the string 'search' with the full hyperlink (https://www.google.com/search) behind. The built-in behaviour does not render 'search' but rather the full hyperlink, and I cannot find a way to successfully modify the custom class to do this. At line (*) above I have tried:

```py
return f'<a href="{self.__url}">{self.__url}</a>'
return f'<a href="{self.__url}">{"test_text"}</a>'
```

etc. but so far in vain.

This answer helps a bit but doesn't explicitly use the print function as per my requirements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43254984/1021819

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit jank, but seems to work:

```py
class RenderHyperlink(object):
    def __init__(self, key, link, *args):
        link = link + "/" if not link.endswith("/") else link
        
        for arg in args:
            link += arg + "/"
            
        self.__url = "<a href={}>{}</a>".format(link, key)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
        display(HTML(self.__url))
        return "" # hacky way to return a string despite not returning anything


# notice that you can also add other parameters to the link
print(RenderHyperlink("search", "https://www.google.com/search", "hello"))
```

Output:
The link points to "https://www.google.com/search/hello/"
[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you! What is the best way to adapt this to allow for text on the same line before (or after) the `RenderHyperlink()` string? Right now if I do `print('Link:',RenderHyperlink(...))` then 'Link:' and the rendered hyperlink appear on two separate lines.

Comment: Add `target=\"_blank\"` to self.__url to have the link open in a new tab instead of taking you away from the notebook.

`self.__url = "<a href={} target=\"_blank\">{}</a>".format(link, key)`

Comment: The last line of `__init__()` should be `self.__url = '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(link, key)`? The double quotes are required for it to be proper HTML.